# pyqt5 fixed window

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Я уже использовал это свойство чтобы задать фиксированную геометрию окна.
Допустим, я сделал разметку на стандартном мониторе 1920x1080, если запустить, то все ок. Но если запустить на мониторе с более высоким разрешением, то все съезжает, так как окно вытягивается по диагонали. Как решить эту проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чем размечал? layout?

Comment: Через дизайнер или ручками?

Comment: сделал сначала без него, потом добавил лейаут на все окно, ничего не поменялось. не подскажете, как правильно привязать лейаут ко всему окну, в котором будет табвиджет?

Comment: использовал дизайнер

Comment: опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Добавь компановщик на окно. В дизайнере на корневом виджете правой кнопкой - компоновка - скомпоновать по вертикали (ctrl+L).

При компановке в python как-то так:

```
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(tabs)
window.setLayout(layout)
```