# Автоматическое расширение PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Учусь работать с `Qt Designer`. Сделал  небольшой ТР.

Но вот проблема, каждый раз при расширении окна все кнопки и поля остаются на месте и образуется пустая зона. Как это фиксится?

Comment: Недавно писал ответ. Щас репостну

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1100263/16574

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, уже сам пофиксил в коде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На свободном месте кликните правой кнопкой мишки и выберите, например как указано на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**test.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>627</width>
    <height>403</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="text">
       <string>TextLabel</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0" colspan="3">
     <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit"/>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="2">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>627</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```